# From xlsx to txt. Any tips on how to speed up this subroutine?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that converts each sheet of a spreadsheet into a txt file.

The code is working well, however given the big amount of exports (abuot 90 txt files) I'd like to seek advice on how to speed this code up.

This is my code:

```
Sub xlsxTotxt()

Dim i As Integer
Dim directory As String
Dim fname As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xTextFile As String
Dim rdate As String

directory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D576").Value
rdate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("E47").Value
i = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value <> ""
fname = Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).Value
Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)
For Each xWs In Workbooks(fname).Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    xTextFile = directory & rdate & " - " & xWs.name & ".txt"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
Workbooks(fname).Close
i = i + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, [so] is mostly for help with problems where code isn't working, but you'll find all the very best of help in optimising your code on [codereview.se].

Comment: Hi Dave, I didn´t know about Code Review, I will now post the question there as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying each sheet

- Save ThisWorkBook
- Select each worksheet
- Save workbook as text - this only saves the select worksheet as text
- Reopen original workbook
- Close last text file

```
Sub xlsxTotxt()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim directory As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xTextFile As String
    Dim rdate As String
    Dim ThisFullName As String
    ThisFullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    directory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D576").value
    rdate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("E47").value
    i = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).value  ""
        fname = Sheets("Macro").Range("D577").Offset(i).value
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fname)
        For Each xWs In Workbooks(fname).Worksheets
            xWs.Select
            xTextFile = directory & rdate & " - " & xWs.Name & ".txt"
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xTextFile, FileFormat:=xlText
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Application.Workbooks.Open ThisFullName
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```